# Finding and printing a specific Pattern in a given string

Tags: python, perl

I am writing a code find a specific pattern in a given string using python or perl. I had some success in finding the pattern using C but python or perl usage is mandatory for this assignment and I am very new in both of these lanuages.

My string looks like this (Amino acid sequence) :-

```
 MKTSGNQDEILVIRKGWLTINNIGIMKGGSKEYWFVLTAENLSWYKDDEEKEKKYMLSVDNLKLRDVEKGFMSSKHIFAL
```

The pattern I want to find is

```
 KXXXXXX(K\R)XR
```

Please note that Letters between K and K\R are not fixed. However, there is only letter between K\R and R. So, in the given string my pattern is like this and exist between letter no. 54 to 65 (if I counted correctly) based on "smallest pattern" search :-

```
  KYMLSVDNLKLR
```

Previously, I was using C if-else condition to break this given string and printed out word count (not fully successful).

```
   printf(%c, word[i]);
     if ((word [i] == 'K' || word [i] == 'R' )) && word [i+2] == 'R') {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
```

I agree It dint capture everything. If anyone can help me help me solving this problem, that would be great.

Comment: Why would it be `KEKKYMLSVDNLKLR`? You can also match
`KTSGNQDEILVIRKGWLTINNIGIMKGGSKEYWFVLTAENLSWYKDDEEKEKKYMLSVDNLKLR`.
In other words, should the matching be greedy or non-greedy? Anyway, regex is indeed the way to go.

Comment: It should be non-greedy. Thanks I will edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want the match to be non-greedy, but that doesn't make sense. I think you are trying to find the minimal match. If so, that's very hard to do. This is the regex match you need:

```
/
    K
    (?: (?: [^KR] | R(?!.R) )+
    |   .
    )
    [KR]
    .
    R
/sx
```

---

However, it wouldn't surprise me if there's a bug. The only sure way to find a minimal match is to find all possible matches.

```
my $match;
while (/(?= ( K.+[KR].R ) )/sxg) {
    if (!defined($match) || length($1) > length($match)) {
        $match = $1;
    }
}
```

But this will be far slower, especially for long strings.

Comment: `      #/usr/bin/env python
       import rem = 'MKTSGNQDEILVIRKGWLTINNIGIMKGGSKEYWFVLTAENLSWYKDDEEKEKKYMLSVDNLKLRDVEKGFMSSKHIFAL'

for m in re.finditer(r'K (?: [^KR] | R(?!.R) )* [KR] . R', m):
     print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
`

Comment: `for m in re.finditer(r'K (?: [^KR] | R(?!.R) )* [KR] . R', m):
     print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))`

Comment: Do you think above implemention is correct ? Since it's not working.

Comment: I don't know Python. You probably need to remove the whitespace or provide a flag to cause it to be ignored.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot @ikegami

Comment: it Works as charm.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the language, this looks a task suitable for regular expressions.

Here is an example of how you could do the regex in python.  If you want the index where the match starts, you can do:

```
m = re.search(r'K(?:[A-JL-Z]+?|K)[KR][A-Z]R', s)
print m.start()  # prints index
print m.group()  # prints matching string
```

Or as @bunji points out, you an use `finditer` as well:

```
for m in re.finditer(r'K(?:[A-JL-Z]+?|K)[KR][A-Z]R', s):
    print m.start()  # prints index
    print m.group()  # prints matching string
```

Comment: Hi, 
Does this module has an option to print the location I mean from where to where this pattern is found ?

Comment: @Vikas If you use `re.finditer()` instead of `re.findall()` it will return match objects and you can use `.start()` and `.end()` functions to get the index of each match in your string.  See this example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs-and-their-positions

Comment: @ikegami I don't think KKXR is a valid match, at least according to OP

Comment: `KXXXXXX(K\R)XR `

Comment: @BrendanAbel It's matching a long string. I am looking non-greddy match. Output

Comment: @ikegami No, any number of letters can be present between K and K/R but I need to find the smallest. KKXR could not be choice.

Comment: @ikegami I meant KK can't be adjacent. At least one letter should be there between them.

Comment: @ikegami I want this : KYMLSVDNLKLR

Comment: @Vikas Dubey, That's useless. That question is: What do you mean by non-greedy match?

Comment: @ikegami I don't know I am using this term on DeepSpace suggestion.  I thought It's related to find out smallest pattern.

Comment: huh? You say you want something, but you don't know what you mean by it???

Comment: @ikegami Ah, I see what the OP wants now.  Updated so it returns the shortest match.

Comment: Ah, forget to make it non-greedy.  Good catch on `KKKXR`, didn't even think of that one.  Updated to handle that scenario.

Comment: Ok, that works   (For now. It'll break if you add another non-greedy to the pattern. Non-greedy modifiers should be avoided except as an optimization.)

Answer (score 0):

Only did it this way because I hate back tracking in my regular expressions.  But I do find its usually faster if I perform the most restrictive part of the match first.  Which in this case is made simpler by reversing the input and the search pattern.  This should stop at the first (shortest) possible match; rather than finding the longest match, then hunting down the shortest.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = "MKTSGNQDEILVIRKGWLTINNIGIMKGGSKEYWFVLTAENLSWYKDDEEKEKKYMLSVDNLKLRDVEKGFMSSKHIFAL";
my $reverse = reverse $pattern;
my $length  = length $reverse;
if( $reverse =~ /(R.[KR][^K]+K)/ ) {
    my $match   = $1;
    $match      = reverse $match;
    my $start_p = $length-$+[0];
    my $end_p   = $length-$-[0]-1;
    my $where   = $start_p + length $match;
    print "FOUND ...\n";
    print "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n";
    print $pattern."\n";
    printf "%${where}s\n", $match;
    print "Found pattern '$match' starting at position '$start_p' and ending at position '$end_p'\n";
    # test it
    if( $pattern =~ /$match/ ) {
        if( $start_p == $-[0] && $end_p == $+[0]-1 ) {
            print "Test successful, match found in original pattern.\n";
        } else {
            print "Test failed, you screwed something up!\n";
        }
    } else {
        print "Hmmm, pattern '$match' wasn't found in '$pattern'?\n";
    }
} else {
    print "Dang, no match was found!\n";
}
```

I'm not certain if the elimination of back-tracking here would outweigh the performance hit of the reversing.  I guess it would depend greatly on the sizes of both the input string and the length of what could possibly match.

```
$> perl ./search.pl
FOUND ...
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
MKTSGNQDEILVIRKGWLTINNIGIMKGGSKEYWFVLTAENLSWYKDDEEKEKKYMLSVDNLKLRDVEKGFMSSKHIFAL
                                                     KYMLSVDNLKLR
Found pattern 'KYMLSVDNLKLR' starting at position '53' and ending at position '64'
Test successful, match found in original pattern.
```

I apologize to those that don't understand why I started at zero.

And a bit more real world example - which will find interwoven matches.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# NOTE THE INPUT WAS MODIFIED FROM OP
my $input = "MKTSGNQDEILVIRKKRKRRGWKLTINNIRGRIMRGRKGGSKEYWFVLTAENLSWYKDDEEKEKKYMLSVDNLKLRDVEKGFMSSKHIFALKGR";

my $rstart = length $input;
my( $match, $start, $end ) = rsearch( $input, "R.[KR].+?K" );
while( $match ) {
    print "Found matching pattern '$match' starting at offset '$start' and ending at offset $end\n";
    $input = substr $input, 0, $end;
    ( $match, $start, $end ) = rsearch( $input, "R.[KR].+?K" );
}
exit(0);

sub rsearch {
    my( $input, $pattern ) = @_;
    my $reverse = reverse $input;

    if( $reverse =~ /($pattern)/ ) {
        my $length = length $reverse;
        $match = reverse $1;
        $start = $length-$+[0];
        $end   = $length-$-[0]-1;
        return( $match, $start, $end );
    }

    return( undef );
}

perl ./search.pl
Found matching pattern 'KHIFALKGR' starting at offset '85' and ending at offset 93
Found matching pattern 'KYMLSVDNLKLR' starting at offset '64' and ending at offset 75 
Found matching pattern 'KLTINNIRGRIMRGR' starting at offset '22' and ending at offset 36
Found matching pattern 'KLTINNIRGR' starting at offset '22' and ending at offset 31
Found matching pattern 'KRKRR' starting at offset '15' and ending at offset 19 
Found matching pattern 'KKRKR' starting at offset '14' and ending at offset 18
Found matching pattern 'KTSGNQDEILVIRKKR' starting at offset '1' and ending at offset 16
```

Comment: This approach occurred to me, but I rejected it because it doesn't work. It fails for `KXXXXRXRXXXRXR`. Note that the solution my answer has no backtracking, just a single character lookahead like yours (or three in the rare case that the `(?!)` is entered).

Comment: Matching twice is a fail?

Comment: No, finding a non-minimal solution is